# Is NX package-based monorepo do not work with Angular?

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-monorepo

My goal is to create module federation example with package-based monorepo angular. Package-based monorepo because I am expecting this scenario:

1. `/checkout` with Angular 15.
2. `/product` with Angular 16.

I am following this tutorial https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/module-federation-with-ssr but with `package-based monorepo`

The problem: I can't go to path `/checkout` or `/product`.

[image]

What I've tried:

1. use integrated monorepo. `/checkout` and `/product` works.
2. use package-based monorepo with react. `/checkout` and `/product` works.

Answer (score 0):

`NG0203` is caused by having multiple copies of `@angular/core`.

All apps should rely on the same core package.

Comment: So you can't have `/checkout` Angular 15 and  `/product` Angular 16? Honestly, I do not know where to start to ask question about Nx. I am confused because I am new with Nx and did not see any difference in the code between package-based monorepo and integrated monorepo. Both use the same package.json.